# What's the difference between .sink and Subscribers.Sink?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I want to do an asynchronous job with Future.
But the below **.sink() closures** never get called.
It seems that the instance of Future was released right after it was called.

```
    Future<Int, Never> { promise in
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            promise(.success(1))
        }
    }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print(completion)
    }, receiveValue: {
        print($0)
    })
```

So I replaced **.sink() closures** to **.subscribe(Subscribers.Sink())** like below. It works fine.
But the problem is I don't understand why it works fine. :(
It looks the same to me.
What is the difference between these two codes? And when can I use **.sink()**, and when can I not?

```
    Future<Int, Never> { promise in
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            promise(.success(1))
        }
    }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .subscribe(Subscribers.Sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print(completion)
    }, receiveValue: {
        print($0)
    }))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question! I don't know the answer, but I can tell you that code is a [mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun), so these are not known as "codes". Instead, they are "pieces of code". ‍♂️

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `.sink` operator does three things:

- It creates a `Subscribers.Sink` using the two closures you pass it.
- It calls `subscribe` on the upstream `Publisher`, passing the `Sink` it created.
- It creates an `AnyCancellable` that, when destroyed, cancels the `Sink`. It returns a reference to this `AnyCancellable`.

`AnyCancellable` is a reference-counted object. When the last reference to the `AnyCancellable` is destroyed, the `AnyCancellable` itself is destroyed. At that time, it calls its own `cancel` method.

In your first example, you are not saving the `AnyCancellable` returned by `.sink`. So Swift destroys it immediately, which means it cancels the subscription immediately. One second later, your `asyncAfter` closure calls `promise`, but the subscription has already been cancelled, so your `receiveValue` closure is not called.

In your second example, since you are creating the `Subscribers.Sink` object and passing it to `subscribe` yourself, no `AnyCancellable` is created to wrap the `Sink`. So nothing automatically destroys the subscription. One second later, the `asyncAfter` closure calls `promise`. Since the subscription wasn't destroyed, it still exists, so your `receiveValue` closure is called, and then your `receiveCompletion` closure is called.

So this is actually a very interesting use of `Subscribers.Sink` instead of the `.sink` operator. With `.sink`, you **must** save the returned `AnyCancellable`, else the subscription is cancelled immediately. But by using `Subscribers.Sink` directly, you create a subscription that lasts until it is completed, and you don't have to save anything. And when the subscription completes (with either `.finished` or `.failure`), the `Sink` discards the `Subscription`, which breaks the retain cycle that was keeping it alive, so the `Sink` and the `Subscription` are also destroyed, leaving no memory leaks.

Comment: Interesting, so it's using an intentional strong retain cycle as a way of keeping both the subscription and sink alive until the cancel event arrives? Is there an external way to cause it to stop?

Comment: `Subscribers.Sink` conforms to `Cancellable`. If you save the `Sink` in your own property, you can call its `cancel` method directly.

Comment: Oh neat! Thanks for sharing

Comment: Is there a way to extract the `Subscribers.Sink` object passed to an `AnyPublisher`? Because if I have to save the `Subscribers.Sink` to an external class property to call `cancel()` from elsewhere then it's the same thing as calling sink and saving the AnyCancelable it returns as a class property.

Comment: No, there is no way to get the subscribers out of an `AnyPublisher` or any other `Publisher` supplied in the SDK. If you want to cancel the subscription, you should just use `.sink`.